# Which trained embeddings vectors from Gensim (word2vec model) should be used for Tensorflow? Unnormalised or normalised ones?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I want to use the Gensim (word2vec model) trained vectors inside a neural network (Tensorflow). There are two kinds of weights I can use for this purpose. The first group is `model.syn0` and the second group is `model.vectors_norm` (after calling `model.init_sims(replace=True)`). The second one is the group of vectors we use for calculating similarity. Which one has the correct order (match with `model.wv.index2word` and `model.wv.vocab[X].index`) and weights for the embedding layer of a neural network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google's`GoogleNews-vectors` as pretrained model you can use `model.syn0`. If you are using Facebook's `fastText` word embeddings you can directly load the binary file.
Below are the example to load both the instances.

**Load GoogleNews pretrained embedding:**

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz',binary=True,limit=500000) # To load the model first time.
model.wv.save_word2vec_format(model_path) #You can save the loaded model to binary file to load the model faster
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load(model_path,mmap='r')
model.syn0norm = model.syn0
index2word_set = set(model.index2word)

model[word] gives the vector representation of the word which can be used to find similarity.
```

**Load fastText pretrained embeddings:**

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import FastText
model = FastText.load_fasttext_format('cc.en.300') # to load the model for first time.
model.save("fasttext_en_bin") # Save the model to binary file to load faster.
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load("fasttext_en_bin",mmap="r")
index2word_set = set(model.index2word)

model[word] gives the vector representation of the word which can be used to find similarity.
```

General example:

```
if word in index2word:
   feature_vec = model[word]
```

Comment: Why do you use `model.syn0norm = model.syn0`?

Comment: @Eghbal That line basically prevents the recalculation of the normalised vectors to improve the speed. Since the similarly operations has to be done on the unit normalized vectors.

Comment: I think still the main question is not answered here. Should we use normalised weights from Gensim or just `syn0` for using these weights in a neural network?

Comment: You can use `syn0`.